# Is firebase 3 release is compatible with firebase-util

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-util

Is firebase-util and angularfire are compatible with new firebase 3.0 release ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AngularFire2 is currently not on new Firebase 3.0 SDK, but there is an update in progress

Answer (score 0):

The AngularFire 2.x releases are compatible with version 3.x of the Firebase SDK for JavaScript: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire

There is as of yet no release of firebase-util that is compatible with version 3.x of the Firebase SDK for JavaScript. You can track progress/demand for that in [this issue in the Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util/issues/96).

Answer (score 0):

Not the complete but here is alpha version available for use

https://github.com/GartorwareCorp/firebase-util

Also, you can check issue on GitHub

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util/issues/96